# How to build a typescript function that returns an record with the given keys from another object

Tags: typescript, key, record

I need to build a function that takes 0 or more keys from a given object and returns a record with those given keys only.

I know, however, how to request a parameter that is an array of keys from an object:

```
function myFunc<T>(field: (keyof T)[]): void {}
```

Problem is that I'm not sure how to make it so that instead of returning void, it returns a record with the given fields as keys:

```
function myFunc<T, K extends (keyof T)[]>(fields: K): Record<K, number> {}
```

This yields `Type 'K' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.` which is fair.

To make it clearer, this would be the implementation of this function in javascript:

```js
function myFunc(fields) {
   return fields.reduce((result, key, idx) => ({...result, [key]: idx}), {});
}
```

And this would be an example of the input and expected output for that function:

```
type Person = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  citizen: boolean
}

console.log(myFunc<Person>(['name', 'citizen'])); // Object { name: 0, citizen: 1 }
console.log(myFunc<Person>(['name', 'years'])); // Error: Argument of type '"years"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "age" | "citizen"'
```

It looks like it should be a very trivial thing that I'm missing completely but I can't find the solution even by searching on internet

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
type Person = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    citizen: boolean
}


type Result<Fields extends PropertyKey[]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Fields as Fields[Prop] extends Fields[number] ? Fields[Prop] : never]: Exclude<Prop, number>
}

function withObj<Obj,>(obj: Obj): <Field extends keyof Obj, Fields extends Field[]>(fields: [...Fields]) => Result<Fields>
function withObj<Obj,>(obj: Obj) {
    return (fields: string[]) =>
        fields.reduce((result, key, idx) => ({ ...result, [key]: idx }), {});
}

const myFunc = withObj({
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    citizen: true
})

const x = myFunc(['name', 'citizen']) // ok
x.name // 0
const y = myFunc(['name', 'years']) // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2pL8m)

`Result` iterates through each array prop and check whether Fields[index] is a subtype of array elements. If yes - rename array key to appropriate array element and use index in a place of a value.

Also, I have added curried version of `myFunc` just for the proper inference.

Comment: I've learnt a ton with your reply! Just for that, thanks a lot! The curried function is a very interesting approach to solve the issue of TS requiring you to provide both type parameters if you attempt to do `function withObj<Obj, Field extends keyof Obj>(...) { ... }`. The `Result` type is also very interesting too as I didn't know you could do that. In my case, tho, I don't need to declare the exact index. As long as it is `number` is enough so making the curried function to return `Record<Fields[number], number>` does already the trick. Thanks so much for this very interesting approach!

Comment: @carlosV2 thank you for your feedback, you can check my [blog](https://catchts.com/) for other solutions. It is fully dedicated to typescript static typings. All examples are taken from real life examples (stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks, will definitely do. I find the TS documentation very useful but it suffers from being very theoretical. Sometimes, practical use cases like yours are really needed to progress further.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want your function to return an object with keys from argument and integral values, but only if values in array are keys of T.

This may be sufficient:

```
function myFunc<T>(fields: (keyof T)[]): Partial<Record<keyof T, number>> {
  return fields.reduce((result, key, idx) => ({ ...result, [key]: idx }), {});
}
```

More accurate would be:

```
function myFunc<T>(fields: (keyof T)[]): Record<typeof fields[number], number> {
  return fields.reduce(
    (result, key, idx) => ({ ...result, [key]: idx }),
    {}
  ) as Record<typeof fields[number], number>;
}
```

Since it uses for keys values in argument array. However, we need to use `as`, since {} confuses typescript, because {} is of type Partial and typescript cannot determine that it becomes full ReturnType at end of reduce.

Another possibility, but very verbose. Note use of `as const` and `readonly`:

```
function myFunc<H, T extends keyof H>(
  fields: readonly T[]
): Record<typeof fields[number], number> {
  return fields.reduce(
    (result, key, idx) => ({ ...result, [key]: idx }),
    {}
  ) as Record<typeof fields[number], number>;
}

type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  citizen: boolean;
};

// const array = ["name", "citizen", "year"] as const // -> Type '"name" | "citizen" | "year"' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof Person'.
const array = ["name", "citizen"] as const;
const result = myFunc<Person, typeof array[number]>(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Matija. It looks like a good approach but, unfortunately, it does not work. I can't seem to be able to restrict it to only the keys passed in `fields`. When I use your code (second function), the result is `Record<keyof Person, number>` which fails to only have the passed keys.

Comment: Please see edited answer. Probably its possible to make it slightly more compact, but its getting tricky.

Comment: That's it! The `as const` and `readonly` is what makes TS to switch from `string` to literal strings that can be used as keys. I like the simplicity of your solution. Unfortunately, I can only accept 1 solution and, since "captain-yossarian from Ukraine"'s reply aligns a bit better with what I need, I'll approve their instead but I'm sure I'll use your approach many uncountable other times. Thanks a lot!